# Meaning of "binge"?

Tags: meaning, colloquialisms, phrase-meaning

What does it really mean? And what do *binge-watching*; *binge-reading*; *binge-eating* mean?

Answer (score 3):

Binge as a modifier for an activity indicates that the activity is performed both episodically and excessively.

A binge-drinker (which was the most common original use) is one who "goes on a binge". This implies that s/he gets very drunk, but not all the time. If it were all the time, it would be chronic or habitual.

Answer (score 0):

If you do too much of a certain activity in a short amount of time, you're going on a binge. So binge-watching could be watching three movies in a row.